# How do you get the type of an impl block in a Rust procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write a Rust procedural macro that can be applied to an impl block like this;

```
struct SomeStruct { }

#[my_macro]
impl SomeStruct { }
```

I'm using syn and quote to parse and format `TokenStream`s in the macro. It looks something like this:

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_macro(meta: TokenStream, code: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(code as ItemImpl);

    // ...

    TokenStream::from(quote!(#input))
}
```

Is there a way to access the type name of the impl block using syn? I don't see any field in `ItemImpl` that gives me that information.

Comment: You ask about "the associated type", but that's a *specific concept* (`impl X { type ThisIsAnAssociatedType }`) that your example doesn't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.23/syn/struct.ItemImpl.html) lists 9 fields on an `ItemImpl`:

1. `attrs: Vec<Attribute>`
2. `defaultness: Option<Default>`
3. `unsafety: Option<Unsafe>`
4. `impl_token: Impl`
5. `generics: Generics`
6. `trait_: Option<(Option<Bang>, Path, For)>`
7. `self_ty: Box<Type>`
8. `brace_token: Brace`
9. `items: Vec<ImplItem>`

Only one of those has the word "type" in it: `self_ty`.

```
use syn; // 0.15.23

fn example(input: syn::ItemImpl) {
    println!("{:#?}", input.self_ty);
}

fn main() {
    let code = syn::parse_str(
        r###"
        impl Foo {}
        "###,
    )
    .unwrap();

    example(code);
}
```

```
Path(
    TypePath {
        qself: None,
        path: Path {
            leading_colon: None,
            segments: [
                PathSegment {
                    ident: Ident(
                        Foo
                    ),
                    arguments: None
                }
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked at self_ty but got lost somewhere in the Type enum and never found that there's a Path value that might have the information I was looking for. Still getting used to Rust.
Now I have to figure out how to get the useful information out there and what to do if the Type has one of the other enum values :-).